# SSRS Blank Parameters

Tags: database, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have 3 simple parameters, all which are text, and allow for multiple values as well as blank values. There are no available values or default values, as I want the users to type the value themselves. When leaving all parameters blank, no data is shown, because there are no blank values. However, I want to show all data when there is no value entered for the parameter. How can I do this?

This is what the query looks like right now

```
SELECT  [PROGRAMNO]
      ,[ACCTNO]
      ,[CLAIMNO]
      ,[TOTALCHARGES]
      ,[TOTALPAYMENT]
      ,[TYPE]
  FROM DATALINE
WHERE PROGRAMNO IN (@PROGRAMNO)
  AND ACCTNO IN (@ACCTNO)
  AND CLAIMNO IN (@CLAIMNO)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an **OR** to allow for the NULL (or blank) value for each condition - depending on which you have allowed in the parameter.

```
WHERE (PROGRAMNO IN (@PROGRAMNO) OR @PROGRAMNO is null)
  AND (ACCTNO IN (@ACCTNO) OR @ACCTNO IS NULL)
  AND (CLAIMNO IN (@CLAIMNO) OR @CLAIMNO IS NULL)
```

or if you allow blank values instead:

```
WHERE (PROGRAMNO IN (@PROGRAMNO) OR @PROGRAMNO = '' )
  AND (ACCTNO IN (@ACCTNO) OR @ACCTNO = '' )
  AND (CLAIMNO IN (@CLAIMNO) OR @CLAIMNO = '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-value parameters do not allow blank input. So you will need to add an item to your dropdown list that represents the blank value. If you are manually specifying the available values you would simply add this to the list. The value would be blank and the label could be something like "Blank" or "N/A". If you are using a query to populate the available values you will need to `UNION` this blank value to the other results. Either way, you'll also need to account for this in your `WHERE` clause in the main dataset as Hannover Fist pointed out.